# Deserialize to a dynamically loaded class

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I have to deserialize below XML.But i have to store Sensor data to a dynamically loaded class.
How can i do that?

**XML format**

```
   <Root>
        <Sensor id="0" Channel="1000">
            <SensorName>RM-T</SensorName>
            <SensorValue>148.00</SensorValue>
        </Sensor>
        <Sensor id="1" Channel="1001">
            <SensorName>SAT1</SensorName>
            <SensorValue>148.00</SensorValue>
        </Sensor>
    </Root>
```

**Main class to store deserialized data**

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Root")]
public class Controller
{        
    public List<Sensor> SensorList
    {
        get;
        set;
    }       
}
```

**Sensor Class**

```
   public abstract class Sensor
    {
        String SensorName { get; set; }
        String SensorValue { get; set; }   
        public abstract override String ToString();     
    }
```

**RegularSensor Class**

```
    public class RegularSensor : Sensor
    {

        public override string ToString()
        {
           //Implementation goes here
        }
    }
```

During deserialization i need to load sensor data to RegularSensor class
How can i do that?

Comment: Why does it need to be dynamic? Looks pretty static to me..

Comment: The XML is from a hardware a controller depending upon the controller the data handling will change.So there will be different implementation for Sensorvalue. In future there will be different function in the abstact class with different implementation

Comment: ...but SensorValue is an attribute in your example.. not the root object. Are you saying the root object (structural layout of the xml) will change? Or just values?

Comment: Structure the XMl will not change.But alias name of the nodes may change.For eg in some XML 'SensorValue' will be 'Value'

Comment: In java i did the same using this code - XStream xStreamXmlSerializer = new XStream(new DomDriver());  
  xStreamXmlSerializer.alias("Sensor", RegularSensor.class);

Comment: Check below link
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14108509/deserialize-a-class-with-interface][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14108509/deserialize-a-class-with-interface

Answer (score -1):

Is this ok for you :

```
 public class RegularSensor : Sensor
    {
        Sensor mySensor = new Sernsor();
        public override string ToString()
        {
           //Implementation goes here
        }
    }
```

and then deserialize this object 'mySensor' in a function.And you can get all datas.

Comment: So.. inheritance **AND** composition? ...why?